# gtk3 theme not working

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk3

the theme I'm trying to install has three folders:
metacity, gtk2 and gtk3
if i activate it using gnome-tweak-tool it wont work everything looks extremely ugly, not the way it's supposed to be transparent, some colors don't even change
if i remove gtk2 folder, theme wont show up in gnome-tweak-tool at all

(i had this problem ever since 11.04, also on 11.10, i hoped it would be fixed in 12.04 but same result here, with 'every theme')

link to theme http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Black-n-White-GTK?content=149636 
what it looks like:
[image: a]
what it should look like:
[image: b]

Comment: wow that looks amazing. I don't know how to help you but I hope someone does because I want this too!

Comment: yeah i thought someone will find it amazing too :D, believe it or not, i'm installing 'arch' on my system right now, just to see how this theme actually looks

Comment: thats commitment! I'll test it on fedora now to check that it's not a gnome shell thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that gnome 3.4 totally changed the way themes are written, which means, gtk3.2 themes (including this one) wont work on gnome3.4
one way is to downgrade to gnome3.2 from 3.4

there are 'a few' (very few) themes ported to gnome 3.4

 and as far as i know theme developers are not so happy about this too, i guess, talked to some of them, they aren't happy!

Comment: I'm a just a regular user.. and I  am unhappy about this as well.  Its not as if we even had an abundance of gtk3 themes, we were still feeling the sting from our last transition.

Answer (score 1):

The transition is indeed painful. Here in xubuntu precise all gtk3-based apps (like the update manager) are not themed.

One solution is to copy the gtk3 subdir of the theme to ~/.config as explained [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119251) but it does not work well, all widgets are not themed, it's a mess. I'm going to wait a little before I configure/compile apps with gtk3.